# hash generated on register not same as on login

Tags: php, mysql

I generate a hashed password on user registration but when trying to log in the hashed password generate is different so i cant log in

reg: (ill be adding checks and verification once i get hashed password working)

```
session_start();    

require_once('connect.php');

$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$cpassword = $_POST['cpassword'];


if($login == '') {
    echo "Email missing";
}
if($password == '') {
    echo "Password missing";
}
if($cpassword == '') {
    echo "Password missing";
}
if( strcmp($password, $cpassword) != 0 ) {
    echo "Passwords do not match";
}

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO members (Email, Password) VALUES (:login, :password)");
$stmt->bindValue( ":login", $login );
$stmt->bindValue( ":password", hash("sha512", $password, $salt));
$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt)
{
    header("location: ?p=register-success");
    exit();
}
```

login:

```
session_start();

include_once ('connect.php');   

$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Password = $_POST['Password'];

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE Email = :Email AND Password = :Password");
$stmt->bindParam(":Email", $Email);
$stmt->bindParam(":Password", hash("sha512", $Password, $salt));
$stmt->execute();
$member = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($member)    
    { 
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['Member_ID'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_POST_AS'] = $member['Post_As'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_AUTH'] = $member['auth'];
            session_write_close();
            header('location: index.php');
    } else  {
        header("location: ?p=login-failed");
    }
```

my salt: (a fixed set of characters for testing only)

```
$salt = "Zo4rU5Z1YyKJAASY0PT6EUg7BBYdlEhPaNLuxAwU8lqu1ElzHv0Ri7EM6irpx5w";
```

i checked if they were the same by echoing the hashed password before they were submitted on a related note, once the hashed password is stored in my table it isnt the same as the one submitted on register the one in the table has ?? in place of some special characters

Comment: Where does that `$salt` come from?

Comment: SHA512 is too fast for password hashing.  Use bcrypt.

Comment: at the moment for the sake of testing if it is working its a fixed set of numbers in my connect.php it will be changed to be based on other factors once i know everything is working

Comment: @SLaks Can you explain how it is too fast for password hashing? Did you mean that it computes to the hash too quickly to be considered safe - as in rainbow tables could be generated for them fairly quickly?

Comment: @crush: After wondering the same thing and doing a bit of research, it appears "fast" refers to the amount of time it takes to generate a single hash.  In that end, bcrypt, since it can have many iterations of rehashing, can take longer.  Which is stronger, however, is up for debate, as the keyspaces are different, SHA2-512 has some security flaws, etc.

Comment: Could you give an example of the hash that is stored and the hash that is generated, so we can see the difference?

Comment: [the third parameter sure ain't _'salt'_](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php), you might want to set it to false & add the thing to the string to be hashed itself, or actually, use [`password_hash`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) or its [userland implementation](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) if you're below PHP 5.5. If you insist on hashing with `true`, the database column should be a _binary_ one, not a `char`-variant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the prototype for the hash function

```
string hash ( string $algo , string $data [, bool $raw_output = false ] )
```

So you need to do something like this:

```
$saltedPwd = $password . $salt;
$hashedSaltedPwd = hash("sha512", $saltedPwd);

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO members (Email, Password) VALUES (:login, :password)");
$stmt->bindValue( ":login", $login );
$stmt->bindValue( ":password", $hashedSaltedPwd);
$stmt->execute();
```

Then make similiar changes to yuor login page.

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter to `hash` determines whether the output from the hash is raw, i.e. not encoded as hexadecimal. Your salt is truthy, so the output is raw, and your database is trying to encode it as a string.

You probably meant to use [`hash_hmac`](http://php.net/hash_hmac). But switch to Bcrypt anyways; a fixed salt isn’t that useful.